# Tapping Android Progress Dialog for Webview Loading - Blank Screen

Tags: android, android-webview, progressdialog

I tried to show a progressDialog while loading content in a Webview. When done, the progressDialog is dismissed.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            //show progress bar
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

I have 2 test device Android 2.3.6 and Android 4.0. In Android 2.3.6, no problem at all. For Android 4.0 tablet, while the progress dialog was displayed, tapping it will hide or remove the progressDialog and will make the screen blank.

What's the problem with my progressDialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your webView Client

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                //show progress bar
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "please wait", "Loading...");
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }


                  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        if (pd.isShowing()) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

        });
    }
```